# Non-trivial subspaces with Set Addition and Intersection

Tags: linear-algebra

**Exercise** Find examples of non-trivial (vector) subspaces $X,Y,Z \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $X+Y = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $X \cap Z = Y \cap Z = \{0 \}$.

---

So, to approach this problem I'm thinking of doing the following:

We should let $X = \{\langle 0, 0 \rangle\} \cup \{\langle 0,b^+ \rangle\} \cup \{a^+,0\}$ such that $a^+,b^+ > 0$ and $Y=\{\langle 0, 0 \rangle\} \cup \{\langle 0,b^- \rangle\} \cup \{a^-,0\}$ such that $a^-,b^- < 0$.

Then $X+Y=\mathbb{R}^2$ since every $\langle a,b \rangle \in \mathbb{R}^2$ can be written as the sum of positive and negative real numbers (adjusting individual coordinates, if necessary).

My biggest issue here is finding a $Z \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $X \cap Z$ and $Y \cap Z = \{\langle 0, 0 \rangle\}$. The *only* non-trivial subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a line through the origin, but one can verify quickly that $X \cap Z$ and $Y \cap Z$ collect many more points than just the zero vector. Thus, my assumption is that my constructions of $X$ and $Y$ are insufficient.

(P.S. There don't even exist three non-trivial subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$?? Can someone explain this as well?)

Comment: Linear subspaces are closed under scalar multiplication so you can't restrict X to be the set of positive numbers. Here, a non-trivial subspace would be a line. As a hint, the set X = {x-axis} and Y = {y-axis} can be used to create any point in $R^2$, meaning that X+Y=$R^2$.

Comment: Ah, so then a good construction would be $X = \{\langle x , 0\rangle: x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $Y= \{\langle 0, y \rangle : y \in \mathbb{R}\}$. What, then, would satisfy $Z$? Would any line work? Say, $Z= \{\langle j, aj \rangle: a, j \in \mathbb{R}\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X = \{\langle x,0\rangle: x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $Y = \{\langle 0,y \rangle: y \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Finally, let $Z= \{\langle x_0, ax_0 \rangle: x_0 \in \mathbb{R}\}$ In this way, we have that $X$ is the set of points lying on the $x$-axis, $Y$ is the set of points lying on the $y$-axis, and $Z$ is any line through the origin.

Note that any vector $v = \langle x , y \rangle \in \mathbb{R}^2$ can be constructed by adding $\langle x,0 \rangle + \langle 0,y \rangle$. This, in fact, is because $v=a_1\hat{i}+a_2\hat{j}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Observe now that $X+Y=\{\langle x+0,0+y\rangle: x,y \in \mathbb{R}\} = \{\langle x,y \rangle: x,y \in \mathbb{R}\} = \mathbb{R}^2$

Also, note that $X \cap Z = \{\langle x,0\rangle: x \in \mathbb{R}\} \cap \{\langle x_0, ax_0\rangle : a,x_0\in \mathbb{R}\}$ = $\{\langle 0,0 \rangle\}$.

Similarly, $Y \cap Z = \{\langle 0, 0 \rangle\}$ and we have completed the problem.